# Removing letters from a string in Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, for-loop

I wrote a function to remove vowels in a given string.

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    text = list(text)
    vowel = 'aeiou'
    for letter in text:
        if letter.lower() in vowel:
            text.remove(letter)
    return ''.join(text)
```

It doesn't remove all of the vowels, when I input 'Hey look Words!' the output is 'Hy lk Words!'

Why doesn't this code remove all vowels in the input?

Comment: See [this](http://arshajii.com/coding-faqs/conc-list-mod.html).

Comment: Seriously, you post an identical code, from a question with 50 upvotes, which has the same output..... How can you miss that. You even named the function the same. What the heck, lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altering the `list` you are looping over could lead into undesired results. Make a copy of it first:

```
for letter in text[:]:
```

Using `[:]` is called list slicing. From [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists):

> All slice operations return a new list containing the requested elements. This means that the following slice returns a shallow copy of the list `a`
>    `>>> a[:]`

The are also other ways to make a copy, like:

```
list(text)
```

Read more aboout [how to make a copy of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2612815/2670792).

Answer (score 2):

You're modifying a list during the iteration. One solution is to iterate over a copy of list. The other solution is to avoid side-effects and go functional:

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    return "".join(c for c in text if c.lower() not in 'aeiou')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex pattern that excludes all vowels with the hat ^

```
import re
pattern = '([^aeiou])'
str_ = "no vowels"
no_vowel_list = re.findall(pattern,str_)
print no_vowel_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    text = list(text)
    result = list()
    for letter in text:
        if letter.lower() not in 'aeiou':
            result.append(letter)
    return ''.join(result)

s = 'Hey look Words!'
print anti_vowel(s)
```

Output:

```
Hy lk Wrds!
```

Comment: Actually this does not answer the question. The question is why, and there is a good answer on the original copy of it =)

Comment: oh ya there is another same question :)